# Using Regex to Find and Replace

Tags: python, regex, function

I would like to take a text document that contains Feet+Frames values and convert them to Timecodes.  For example, 0000+00 is replaced with 00:00:00:00.

I have a function to do the conversion from Feet+Frames to Timecode (16 frames per foot, framerate is 24 frames per second):

```
def FeetFramesToTimecode(FeetFrames):
    frames = int(FeetFrames[:4])*16+int(FeetFrames[-2:])
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" % (frames/(3600*framerate), frames/(60*framerate)%60, frames/framerate%60, frames%framerate)
```

And then I have code that goes through the text file and sub's the Feet+Frame with timecode:

```
for line in input_document:
    found = re.search(r'\d{4}\+\d{2}', line)
    if found:
        print "%s replaces %s" % (FeetFramesToTimecode(found.group()), found.group())
        new_line = re.sub(r'\d{4}\+\d{2}', (FeetFramesToTimecode(found.group()), line)
        output_document.write(new_line)
    else:
        output_document.write(line)
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  How do I get a function to work inside of a re.sub?

Comment: stylistically - please save `CamelCase` for classes and [use `words_separated_by_underscores` for function names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names). (i.e. `def feet_frames_to_time_code(feet_frames)`). This makes it *much* clearer what is going on. (Notice how your question highlights the CamelCase differently then the rest of the code?)

Comment: I learned a new word today... CamelCase.  As I said, I don't know much about programming... much less what a class is.  I'm learning though and appreciate the input.

Comment: Well, if you learned it, may as well say that that’s PascalCase, not camelCase. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code has an extra '(' that does not belong.  This is what the line should be:

```
new_line = re.sub(r'\d{4}\+\d{2}', FeetFramesToTimecode(found.group()), line)
```

This produced output for me like you want.

Comment: Doh!  I feel like Homer on this one.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

`resub` can take a second argument of a callable rather than just the replacement string.

If you pass a callable, it must take the match object.

You should also follow the [python pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) to make the python more readable (for other pythonistas)

Something like:

```
def feetframes_to_timecode(feetframes_match, framerate=24):
    feetframes = feetframes_match.group()
    frames = int(feetframes[:4])*16+int(feetframes[-2:])
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" % (frames/(3600*framerate),
                                    frames/(60*framerate)%60,
                                    frames/framerate%60,
                                    frames%framerate)
# then just use:
for line in input_document:
    output_document.write(re.sub(r'\d{4}\+\d\d', feetframes_to_timecode, line))
```

Comment: I apologize for my bad scripting as I have no formal education on this topic.  I simply have an idea and Google my way to the final script.  I will take a look at whatever pep8 is and try to improve my formatting.  Thanks for all your help on this!

Comment: Ahhh!  I see!  Move the match.group() to the function instead!  That's a good idea.